# ...could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

I am having the common "[could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB" error.  I have tried all of the fixes I could find without success.  I have displayed the skin, I have set the RAM to 512 MB, I have enabled/disabled snapshot, and I have tried other random experiments, but the same error keeps popping up.  Below are the current stats of my emulator.  I have adjusted them all to their origional positions.  The console display is below that.  Any advice would be appreciated!  I am absolutely stuck!

NOTE:  The emulator appears regardless of the changes I have made (including the RAM settings).  It is a black screen for a few seconds followed by the ANDROID logo.

```
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] SD Card already present with same size, was not changed.
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] Updated AVD 'Nexus_7' based on Android 4.2, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Google
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=213
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=-2113695447
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=Nexus 7
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=32
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=1024
```

---

```
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] SD Card already present with same size, was not changed.
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] Updated AVD 'Nexus_7' based on Android 4.2, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Google
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=213
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=-2113695447
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=Nexus 7
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=no
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=32
[2012-12-09 11:00:28 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=1024
[2012-12-09 11:10:21 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2012-12-09 11:10:21 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2012-12-09 11:10:21 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-12-09 11:10:21 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-12-09 11:10:27 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus_7'
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - MyFirstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-12-09 11:10:28 - MyFirstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-12-09 11:10:30 - MyFirstApp] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i uninstalled and reinstalled EVERYTHING.